# Error: MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: c#, mysql

This query works when I type directly into mysql but not in C#.

```
double deltaTime = (DateTime.Now - collectTime).TotalSeconds;


string query = String.Format("UPDATE buildings LEFT JOIN server_buildings ON buildings.global_id = server_buildings.global_id AND buildings.level = server_buildings.level SET buildings.storage = buildings.storage + (server_buildings.speed * {0} * IF(buildings.boost >= NOW(), 2, 1)) WHERE buildings.global_id IN('generator', 'test')", deltaTime / 3600d);
```

Only get the error MySQL - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
Appreciate suggestions! :)

Expected that over time it would add value in "storage"

Comment: Are you sure the error is caused by the above query?

Comment: You shouldn't inject data into your query like that, instead use a parameter.

Comment: Like @Charlieface said, use a `MySqlParameter`, which will encode and escape the data correctly for you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, appreciate all the help! Im fairly new to mysql.
Here it is with parameters.

```
            string query = String.Format("UPDATE buildings JOIN server_buildings ON buildings.global_id = server_buildings.global_id AND buildings.level = server_buildings.level SET buildings.storage = buildings.storage + (server_buildings.speed * ?Num * IF(buildings.boost >= NOW(), 2, 1)) WHERE buildings.global_id IN('generator', 'test')");
                     
            using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter("?Num", (deltaTime / 3600d));
                command.Parameters.Add(param);
      
               command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Comment: Much better. Do note that `string.Format` is not necessary now as there is nothing being injected, and should never be used (as it implies injection). Also that when using other database products such as SQL Server then you should ideally specify the parameter type/precision/length.

Answer (score -2):

Found the solution. Was that my system language is not English.
The solution was:

```
(deltaTime / 3600d).ToString("F7").Replace(",", ".")
```

Comment: Replacing `,` with `.` looks like a hack... you could use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` inside `String.Format`. See https://www.ideone.com/P7rjeh

Comment: Use a `MySqlParameter`, which will encode the value for you correctly.

Comment: You still have SQL injection though

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).